# Variable importance based on predictive R-squared

Tags: importance

I found the paper *Empirical Asset Pricing via Machine Learning*. Accesible, for example, via https://dachxiu.chicagobooth.edu/download/ML.pdf. The authors state on page 2247

> We discover influential covariates by ranking them according to a notion
>   of variable importance, which we denote as $VI_j$ for the $j$th input variable.
>   We consider two different notions of importance. The first is the reduction in
>   panel predictive $R^2$ from setting all values of predictor $j$ to zero, while holding
>   the remaining model estimates fixed (used, e.g., in the context of dimension
>   reduction by Kelly, Pruitt, and Su 2019). The second, ....

This seems like a nice way to do variable importance selection. It seemed to me that it solves the problem of highly correlated variables (maybe I am wrong?). I did not see this method before, and I find it hard to find a good source online. Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: Why do you think it solved the highly correlated problem? If multiple variables are highly correlated, ablating any of them might have minor impact on $R^2$. Then how do you do variable selection?

Comment: Yes, I agree. No, it doesn't. You are right.